# Numeric value does not fit in a System.Decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, postgresql, precision

I am using a Postgres database with Entity Framework.

In my database there is a table which has column `price (numeric)` and values like `12314.0464314894136514658489431486146548`

When I get data using a LINQ query, it throws an error:

> An exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Numeric value does not fit in a System.Decimal

In my model class the `price` property has data type of `decimal(19,4)`

What I was thinking that the values from DB table has greater precision, and my model property has less precision,

So my question: is there any way to get the data from the database table with truncated/rounded values, that will fit in my model property?

Note: I am restricted to not make any changes to the database, all I have to do in my C# code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am afraid this value is indeed out of range for Decimals in C#. Is rounding an option?

Also have a look at libraries that implement BigDecimal type in .NET, for example this one https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136

Comment: That's not a `decimal(19,4)`. There are over 30 decimals in there instead of 4. Is the field a float perhaps? How was *this* value stored? Please post the schema, classes and query.

Comment: If you want the field to have a specific scale use `NUMERIC(19,4)`, not `NUMERIC`. NUMERIC accepts up to [16383 decimal digits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html). Also check how you *store* the values. Did you really want to store a value with over 30 decimals?

Comment: Could you tell us what is type of this field in the database? The value in your example does not correspond to NUMERIC(19,4) you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In database, the price field has data type `numeric` ,  I don't know how these values had inserted, I provided with database and asked to fetch data from it. Query is `var result = context.books.Where(x => x.name == "My Book").ToList();`

Comment: `numeric` accepts thousands of digits. If you *don't* want them, you should use a more sensible scale. If you expect (19,4) you should use `numeric(19,4)`. You should probably notify whoever provided the database that they have data problems. Most likely, they tried to store floats instead of a numeric value with a defined precision. That's probably a bug in their data input

Comment: My crystal ball says that the dbase column is not numeric but a string and that your local culture uses a comma as the decimal separator.  So you asked the wrong question, I suspect you'll have to get `to_number()` going in your Postgres SQL statement.  Or byte the bullet and make it a string in your model that you convert yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Select query in `.edmx` file, solve my problem of precision.

Navigate to the `<EntitySet>` tag, and add the select query.

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema>
        <EntityContainer>
            <EntitySet Name="books" EntityType="Self.books" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="public">
                <DefiningQuery>SELECT "books"."name", (("books"."price")::double precision)::numeric FROM "public"."books" AS "books"</DefiningQuery>
            </EntitySet>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
```

Now when I select that column, using below query, it returns the value that will properly fits in decimal data type of c#, there is no need to do any changes in database.

```cs
var result = context.books.Where(x => x.name == "My Book").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You may round the Price field values on the database level. Try this

```
var myRecords = model.Database
.SqlQuery<MyRecord>("select ..., cast(Price as numeric(19,4)) from mytable");
```

Comment: I have to use LINQ, not a raw query, because LINQ is very useful for me on my further development, is there any way to do that task using LINQ ?

Comment: You may apply linq extension on myRecords (e.g. myRecords.Where(...).Select(...), and etc.) but they will not affect to actual sql query. If you can add a VIEW to the database, you can easy solve it but you told you are not permitted to do any changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive the values as text and four decimals is what you need, you could transform like this:

```
decimal d = 0;
d = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("12314.0464314894136514658489431486146548"), 4));

// d -> 12314.0464
```

Comment: Note that the input is *not* a decimal with scale 4, ie 4 decimals

Comment: Converting to double then decimal seems like a bad idea. Truncating the string first would seem to be the best option.

Comment: @ChrisF something is wrong with the value itself. It's definitely not (19,4). The bug is probably in the field definition or the way the data is stored. There may be no reason to change how the value is loaded.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - True - I thought the value quoted looked strange for a price value, but I was commenting on the usefulness of this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
select round(price,4) from books
```